# How to pause a YouTube video on button click?

Tags: html, css, youtube

```
<a href="#page" class="lil-close">Close</a>
```

I have this button to close a lightbox. The lightbox contains a YouTube video and when I close the lightbox YouTube video keeps playing, I assume this will happen with all videos (not only YouTube). Is there a way (jQuery/JavaScript) to pause video once a user clicks a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function which uses YouTube's API and YouTube's Chromeless Player:

```
function pauseVideo() {
  if (ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.pauseVideo();
  }
}
```

See an example [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player)

Comment: It didn't work with embeded code (iframe) from youtube, but I'll try to play around with api. Thank you for the source.